Call sql view in spring boot
DB has A and B, and I'm going to make a sql view in B, so I'm going to call and use it in A
If you give the select permission and look it up with the DB tool, it can be searched, but if you call it from the server, the error below occurs
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 8
add <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="BATCH"/> not working

What are A and B? Views or tables? Do you use the same user/pass in the DB tool and in the server? What's the specific SQL query that fails? What's the error? You posted the error as 8; I'm sure there's more to it.
